# SOAP-ENV:Server - Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object

Tags: php, soap

I have cron jobs setup to call a SOAP service which does scraping functions. I've been getting errors from one of these scripts which is caught by a catch:

```
Error:  SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in /var/www/run_code.php:38
Stack trace: 

#0 /var/www/run_code.php(38): SoapClient->__call('scrapeRankingsB...', Array) 
#1 /var/www/run_code.php(38): SoapClient->scrapeRankingsBulk('N;', 0, 'a:1:{i:19131;s:...', 50, 'domain.com')
```

Line 38 is this:

```
$results = $client->scrapeRankingsBulk($array,0,$array2,50,'domain.com');
```

I'm establishing a connection with:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://IP?WSDL', array('trace' => 1) );
```

There's absolutely no call to **getAttribute** so I'm wondering why it's complaining about getAttribute? Does it internally call it, or can it only be coming from SoapServer?

On the server, the **scrapeRankingsBulk** method has no direct call to **getAttribute** on the server end. And `/var/log/apache2/error.log` doesn't have any errors logged from the server ( LogLevel=warn ).

Comment: Perhaps `[SOAP-ENV:Server]` indicates that the problem is on the server, and not on the client?

Comment: Yes - but why does it reference the local filename? I guess because there's no reference to it other than calling it from the local filename.

Comment: It seems that when `SoapServer` fails, it returns only the error message (which is something that can be checked in PHP internals). You can simulate this behaviour with [SoapFault](http://php.net/manual/en/soapfault.soapfault.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the stack trace of the exception, you can see that the first parameter is the string `'N;'` even though the variable you passed to it is named `$array`.

I would be very surprised if it is a coincidence that this is what you get if you evaluate `serialize(null)`, which suggests two problems: firstly, should this argument ever be null; and secondly, why has it been run through `serialize`?

Comment: That's the first thing I noticed too. It's a blank array but it somehow seems to work even with that. I'll debug it further though. But why would the stack trace mix the local filename with a remote method call is my main question?

Comment: Well, a SoapFault can be raised either directly by the client or based on an error message transmitted by the server. There are extra fields you can examine, see http://php.net/SoapFault